# Ionic: Unable to align the text of ion-list items

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework

I'm trying to align the text centrally inside the `ion-list` items, using text-align using `text-align: center` inside the following css code:

```
.my-profile-bar-content{
      padding-top:34px ;
      height: 250px;
      text-align: center;
      }
```

But I don't know why I'm getting the first item (the 'Login' one) out of being centered with the others, here is the screenshot:

[image]

And this is my used HTML code:

```
    <ion-popover-view>
  <ion-header-bar class="my-profile-bar-header">
    <span class="my-profile">
      <img src="../img/no-face.png">
      <h1 class="title" style="margin-top: 20px">My Full Name</h1>
      </span>
    </ion-header-bar>
    <ion-content class="my-profile-bar-content">
      <ion-list>
<ion-item menu-close ng-click="login()">
Login
</ion-item>
<ion-item menu-close href="#/app/search">
Search
</ion-item>
<ion-item menu-close href="#/app/browse">
Browse
</ion-item>
<ion-item menu-close href="#/app/playlists">
Playlists
</ion-item>
</ion-list>
    </ion-content>
  </ion-popover-view>
</script>
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of **Developer's Tools** (F12 or right click -> last option) check what additional style rules are applied to this particular menu. It is worth to note that **Login** button is a **button**, not **href**, meaning other style rules for buttons may have interfered.

Comment: Yeah, that was the mistake. Thanks for this helpful answer!